# Open kinect giving errors when I try to compile

Tags: compilation, kinect

I am trying to compile OpenKinect-libfreenect on ubuntu 10.10.
I have installed all the dependencies.
When I compile it with make, it gives me this error.

```
Scanning dependencies of target cppview
[ 64%] Building CXX object examples/CMakeFiles/cppview.dir/cppview.cpp.o
/home/giodamelio/Downloads/OpenKinect-libfreenect-bdd9219/examples/cppview.cpp:41:     fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/cppview.dir/cppview.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/cppview.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `freeglut3-dev` package.